# War Overlay... with Ant?

Tags: java, maven, ant, cas

I've been tasked with setting up a Jasig CAS server, which is a Maven project using the Spring Framework. It uses the Maven War Overlay plugin to combine the CAS server's original files with my custom files.

Unfortunately, I am not permitted to leverage Maven and must therefore convert this to an Ant project.

I am not as knowledgeable with Ant as I am with Maven. Does Ant have a feature comparable to the Maven War Overlay plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`zip`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) task to replace files. See `update` parameter. You may consider it quite a low level solution but it will do just the same thing as Maven plugin do.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I ended up using unzip to expand the war file prior to the compile phase, which was good enough for my purposes.